# How to scale numbers from one range to another range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck in a problem of mapping numbers from one range to another. I want to calculate popularity of a web page based on the number of page hits on a scale of 10. The problem is total number of web pages are around 41,00,000 and the web pages for which page visit is given are only 1,70,000. Also, the page visit for a web page is between 20,000 and 1.

Now, I'll try to rephrase the above problem in more mathematical problem, I have 41,00,000 objects for which I need to calculate some factor "po". Out of these 41,00,000 objects, 1,70,000 objects contain some number 20,000 <=y <= 1. Now how can I calculate "po" for each object on scale of 10.

The data mostly looks like,

```
O1: 20,000
O2: 17,000
O3: 16,000
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
O19: 334
O20: 300
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
On: 1 and so on......
```

Mostly, objects have page visits = 1.

I tried calculating page visit for each object/maximum page visit for an object but that gives me very small values(like 1/20,000 is a very small number). I want my resulatant po values to be at some distance from one another so that I can differentiate between them.

Can anyone please suggest me some solution ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain further what "po" means.  What information are you using to calculate it?

Comment: You could sort the $n$ items in descending order and set $p_i=\frac in$. Yould should also deal with the fact that $O_i$ and $O_{i+1}$ can have the same number of page views, so give them both the value $\frac in$.

Comment: po refers to popularity which I need to calculate foe each object

Comment: @Ragnar: What is i and n in the above formula ?

Comment: $n$ is the number of objects and $i$ is the position of the object when sorted.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to take a range of $[1,20000]$ to $[1,10]$ is to subtract $1$, multiply by $\frac 9{199990}$ and add $1.$  If your division is integer divide, that will collapse many input values to the same output value.  With only $10$ output values, there is no preventing that.  If your division is floating point, $\frac 1{2000}$ is not small, so you can still see differences.

Answer (score 0):

Use the percentile of its position when ordered by number of page visits.  The most frequently visited page is at 100%, the least frequently visited page is 0%.  For example, if you have 4 pages the most frequently visited would be 100%, the second would be 67%, the third 33%, and the lowest would be 0%.

This way you can say "page x is among the top $p$ percent of popular pages."

Comment: how are you calculating the above percentile ? Can you give some sort of formula ?

Comment: Sort the pages by number of visits, so that the most visited is 0, the second most visited is 1, the third most visited is 2, ..., the $k$-th most visited is $k-1$, etc., the least visited is $n$.  Then the percentile of page $k$ is $100\cdot(n-k)/n$.  (Note that there are $n+1$ pages.)